# Separating string with two characters

Tags: c++

I want to separate string by character "," or ";".

```
std::string input = "abc,def;ghi";
std::istringstream ss(input);
std::string token;

while(std::getline(ss, token, ',')) { //how to add here ";"?
    std::cout << token << '\n';
}
```

Comment: you can write function that splits string to strings array by one character, and then use it as many times as needs with different characters.

Comment: First use either , or ;. Then get each token and again tokenize those tokens by other seperator.
e.g. if you first tokenize by ; then get each token and tokenize them again by ,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/1413395

Comment: You can use any tokenizers that already written. boost, poco. You can write your own using "find" function. I don't see problem.

Comment: **-1**, Volz, please, don't be so lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about old way style?

```
std::string string = "abc,def;ghi";
std::vector<std::string>strings;
std::string temp;
for(int i=0; i < string.length(); i++)
{
    if(string[i] == ',' || string[i] == ';')
    {
        strings.push_back(temp);
        temp.clear();
    }
    else
    {
        temp += string[i];
    }
}
strings.push_back(temp);
```

[live demo](http://ideone.com/T3vwkq)

Comment: This is a really meh way of doing it. Could be improved with `std::string::find`, `std::string::substr` etc.

Comment: @Rapptz Yeah i could, i will add it to the answer

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Boost Tokenizer library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.htm):

```
boost::char_separator<char> sep(",;");
boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>> tokens(input, sep);
```

Comment: Including boost for this little peace of code?

Comment: @PaulR i don't think that he will use anything else from boost, so including boost just for tokenizer...

Comment: I still don't see what the objection is - if you're serious about writing C++ code then boost should be part of your weaponry. And of course you only need to include the parts of boost that you need, and these are mostly header-only, i.e. no libraries.

Comment: There's also `boost::split` and `boost::is_any_of`.

Comment: @Rapptz: +1: yes, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/236976/253056)

Answer (score 0):

Using strsep in string.h from C library , you could do it like this:

```
std::string input = "abc,def;ghi";
const char* ss = intput.c_str();
const char token[] = ",;";

for (const char* part; (part = strsep(&ss, token)) != NULL;) {
    std::cout<< part << std::endl;
}
```